# Determining cell value using bitwise operation with adjacent cell values

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

A r*c grid has only 0's ans 1's . In each iteration , if there is any adjacent cell (up,down,left,right) same to it, the value of the current cell will be flipped . Now , how to come up with a bitwise formula to do this . It can be done with a simple if condition , but I want to know the bitwise operation to do this so the whole operation can be done once per row .

I am talking about [this](https://codeforces.com/contest/1349/problem/C) problem . I saw a solution using this concept [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1349/submission/79888368) . But I couldn't understand how this is used to do the determine the cell value by this XOR operations.

```
ans[i] ^= ((l ^ r) | (r ^ u) | (u ^ d)) | (~s[i] ^ l);
ans[i] &= prefix;
```

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the start, **consider `s[i]`, `l`, `r`, `u`, and `d` to be *single* bits, that is, boolean variables**.

- `s[i]` (abbreviated as `s` in this answer) is the old color of the cell to be updated.
- `l`, `r`, `u`, and `d` are the colors of the adjacent cells `left`, `right`, above (`up`), and below (`down`) of the cell to be updated.
- `ans[i]` (abbreviated as `ans` in this answer) is the new color of the cell after the update.
  We initialize `ans = s` and update it only if needed.

Recall the rules from the game for a single cell C:

- If all cells adjacent to C have the opposite color of C, then C retains its color.
- Otherwise (if a cell adjacent to C has the same color as C), C changes its color.

#### Are there various adjacent colors?

For the first condition you can use a fail-fast approach. No matter the color of C, if the adjacent cells have various colors (some are `0` and some are `1`) then C changes its color. To check whether the adjacent cells `l`, `r`, `u`, and `d` have various colors you only need three checks ✱:

```
various_adjacent_colors = (l != r) || (r != u) || (u != d)
```

In bit-wise notation this is
`various_adjacent_colors = (l ^ r) | (r ^ u) | (u ^ d)`

<sub>✱ The "missing" checks like `r != d` are not necessary. Think about it the other way: If all three checks fail, then we know `(l == r) && (r == u) && (u == d)`. In that case, from transitivity of `==` follows that `(l == u)`, and `(l == d)`, and `(r == d)`. Therefore, all colors are the same.</sub>

#### Fail-Fast for various adjacent colors

If we find various adjacent colors, then we change `s`:

```
if (various_adjacent_colors)
  ans = !s
```

In bit-wise notation this is
`ans ^= various_adjacent_colors`

#### Are all colors equal?

If we did not fail-fast, we know that all adjacent colors are equal to each other but not if they are equal to `s`. If `s == all_adjacent_colors` then we change `s` and if `s != all_adjacent_colors` then we retain `s`.

```
if (!various_adjacent_colors && s == l) // l can be replaced by either r, u, or d
  ans = !s
```

In bit-wise notation this is
`ans ^= ~various_adjacent_colors & ~(s ^ l)` or
`ans ^= ~various_adjacent_colors & (~s ^ l)`

#### Putting everything together

Now let's inline (and slightly simplify) all the bit-wise notations:

`vari = (l ^ r) | (r ^ u) | (u ^ d); ans ^= vari; ans ^= ~vari & (~s ^ l)` is the same as
`vari = (l ^ r) | (r ^ u) | (u ^ d); ans ^= vari | (~s ^ l)` is the same as
`ans ^= ((l ^ r) | (r ^ u) | (u ^ d)) | (~s ^ l)`

Seems familiar, right? :)

#### From single bits to bit-vectors

So far, we only considered single bits. The [linked solution](https://codeforces.com/contest/1349/submission/79888368) uses bit-vectors instead to simultaneously update all bits/cells in a row of the 2D game board. This approach only fails at the borders of the game board:

- From `r = s[i] << 1` the game board might end up bigger than it should be. `ans[i] &= prefix` fixes the size by masking overhanging bits.
- At the top and bottom row the update does not work because `u = s[i-1]` and `d = s[i+i]` do not exist. The author updates these rows "manually" in a `for` loop.
- The update for the leftmost and rightmost cell in each row might be wrong since `r = s[i] << 1` and `l = s[i] >> 1` shift in "adjacent" cells of color `0` which are not actually in the game. The author updates these cells "manually" in another `for` loop.

**By the way**: A (better?) alternative to the mentioned "manual" border updates is to slightly enlarge the game board with an additional *virtual* row/column at each border. Before each game iteration, the virtual rows/columns are initialized such that they don't affect the update. Then the update of the actual game board is done as usual. The virtual rows/columns don't have to be stored, instead use ...

```
// define once for the game
bitset<N> maskMsb, maskLsb;
maskMsb[m-1] = 1;
maskLsb[0] = 1;
// define for each row when updating the game board
bitset<N> l = (s[i] >> 1) | (~s[i] & maskMsb);
bitset<N> r = (s[i] << 1) | (~s[i] & maskLsb);
bitset<N> u = i+1 <= n-1 ? s[i+1] : ~s[n-1];
bitset<N> d = i-1 >= 0   ? s[i-1] : ~s[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation . Totally got it now and also got the alternate idea of yours of using dummy row and column for the borders . Will definitely try that . Thanks a lot !